# scrapy! How do you scrape a div that contains this _ngcontent before the class?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Assume the div contains a name of a product:

```
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c225 class="shelfProductTile-content">
```

in scrapy using `response.css('div.shelfProductTile-content')` returns an empty list, how do you overcome this issue?

`Edit:` It was claimed that Javascript web content like AngularJs and react can't be obtained by Scrapy, and it is recommended to use a tool such as Splash or Selenium. That's true, but this was not the case with my example, I tried both of these tools but didn't solve the issue. The problem was with the user-agent that should be changed. please check accepted answer below.
Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: Does the div contain the name of the product in the HTML too, or is it populated by client-side JavaScript? (`_ng` is a hint that this might be an Angular app).

Comment: @AKX it has a header and the header contains this 

<a _ngcontent-serverapp-c225="" class="shelfProductTile-descriptionLink" href="/shop/productdetails/305223/lipton-ice-tea-lemon">Lipton Ice Tea Lemon 1.5l</a>

Comment: @AKX solved, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/71769879/8439065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the user agent in the settings file it solved the issue:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Code should match your element(s):

```py
response.xpath("//div[@class='shelfProductTile-content']")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this didn't work. What worked was changing the user agent https://stackoverflow.com/a/71769879/8439065https://stackoverflow.com/a/71769879/8439065